# How to display a certain value from nested hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying create an app where the user could transform his name  or a word with chemical elements (like breaking bad logo). After couple of questions here, trying, and long reflexion I that I have kinda find the "ideal" solution... *( Humm I hope...)*

I wish that if I enter **acalam** to display the folowing:

[image: symbols]

If no symbol matches I am keepking the initial entry so it could be:
hello => **He** ll **O** (bold char represent the existing chemical symbols)

My model looks like this ( just a couple of symbols for now)

```
class Convertor < ActiveRecord::Base

  def get_chemical
    symbols = {
        "ac" => {
          :chem_name => "Actinium",
          :number => 89,
          :symbol => "Ac",
          :molar => 227
          },
        "al" => {
          :chem_name => "Aluminium",
          :number => 13,
          :symbol => "Al",
          :molar => 26.981539
          },
        "am" => {
         :chem_name => "Americium",
         :number => 95,
         :symbol => "Am",
         :molar => 243
            }
          }

      #not sure how to use this
      result=[]
      symbols.each do |key, value|
        value.each do |key2, value2|
          result << value2
        end
        result
      end


      name.downcase.gsub!(Regexp.union(symbols.keys), symbols) 
   
  end

end
```

This the view

```
  .col-xs-12
    .number
      = @convertor.get_chemical # plus something? 
    .symbol
      = @convertor.get_chemical # plus something?
    .molar
      = @convertor.get_chemical # plus something?
    .chem_name
      = @convertor.get_chemical # plus something?
```

For now my view looks like this  :([image]

## EDIT

These are all the chemical symbols, so do I have to make a condition for each ? Or is there a better way?[image]

Comment: What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: I don't know how to extract the values i need

Answer (score 1):

Symbols are one or two characters long right? You have to decide which of the two are you going to search first: let's say 2 character, then 1.

For "Hello"

Search the hash for the next unmatched pair: He, because is a hash, you don't have to loop, simply ask if the `symbols.include? 'He'`, if it does, move to the next unmatched pair. If it doesn't, search for 'H' alone and repeat.

The first 'l' comes around and it doesn't match, 'll' doesn't match either, simply return 'l', the same with the second 'l' and you end up with

**He** l l **O**

When the hash includes the symbol you want, simply return it:

```
lookup = 'He'
symbols[lookup]
symbols[lookup][:chem_name]
```

Comment: Please see my edit I added the table of the symbols.
Symbols can be 3 char too. 
So I have to do 103 different conditions?

Comment: The only chemical symbols that can be three characters long are both rare and don't make up a word or name; there are few words/names with double-U characters in them. I'd disregard this possibility, at least for a first implementation. It is too remote a possibility.

Comment: your right, but I'll see if I include them because some people may play typing crapy stuff hehe

Comment: Not 103 different conditions, but all symbols need to be in the hash. Then you simply ask the hash up to 3 times: `symbols.include? 'Hel'`, `symbols.include? 'He'` and `symbols.include? 'H'` if you were not to find a result in the first two. Let's not update my answer until we have two figured out, adding 3 char answers, is trivial past that point.